# Digital electronics and number systems

Tags: digital-logic

I have seen a lot of books and chapters on digital electronics. Each and evry of them basically start up with things like Binary numbers,  octal numbers, hexadecimal numbers. Then the course surges towards grey codes, logic gates etc. But I can  never get what is the relation of electronics ,more crudely but precisely, circuits and machines  and this calculation works like binary numbers. I mean how do they relate with practically important quantities like  current and voltage? How do machines use this numbers do perform all the marvels. 
I hope experienced and esteemed people here can explain me what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding just what you are asking. Are you wondering how logic gates can implement complex calculations like a computer does? Or are you wondering what role voltage and current play in the calculations?

Comment: @PhilFrost Yes I am trying to understand how logic gates, binary numbers and the other number systems help in accomplishing all the operations that computer , calculators and cell phones perform ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: Binary numbering system is used, because a switch is either on or off. Logic gates bring you to Boolean math. Computers read/write, compare (<=>), and manipulate (sum/bit shift) data. Programers set the order of the operations, to achieve the desired results. End users, think of it as a magic black box.

Answer (score 3):

The number systems are an abstraction layer on top of actual electronics, just to make the resulting circuit easier to understand, use or program. This way you only have to worry about the top abstraction layer: the numbers, the programming.

In return you don't have to worry about how the underlying components transistors, diodes, output impedance, parasitic capacities, current gain, ..., Miller, Kirchoff, Thévenin, ...  work together.

These are more or less the various abstraction layers:

- binary numbers are long and therefore we like to compress them into triplets (octal) or 4 bits (hexadecimal) or octets (bytes)
- binary numbers are basically used to combine digital signals into a number so we can do calculations/comparisons/...
- boolean (on/off; true/false; 1/0) is the state of a single digital signal
- digital electronics (gates) are built out of analog electronic devices
- analog electronics

Answer (score 2):

I'll keep this brief since this question will soon be closed, but digital numbers are expressed in electronics overwhelmingly in binary.  That way each digit can be represented as a voltage that is either high or low.  Lots of electronics can perform numeric and other digital operations on these high/low voltages.  This is so common, they are called "logic" circuits.

Comment: lanthrop : In my justification, I will just say that I think it is important to first know that for what purpose we use this binary numbers, hexadecimal numbers then to just keep on doing calculations.

Comment: @Prim: So the question is really *why* use numbers? Many reasons. Numbers, as apposed to analog signals, are good for counting things, for example. Even analog measurements are nowadays better converted to digital and manipulated digitally since this can be done in a processor, more accurately than in analog, without drift, etc.  Digital signals can be transmitted without loss, or if there is loss, this can be detected.  Analog signals just degrade whenever they are touched.

Comment: Could you suggest some ebooks or pdf files that explains the intricate details in a nice manner?

Answer (score 1):

The other number systems (octal, hexadecimal) have very little to do with how the circuits work. They are commonly used because, unlike decimal, they map simply to binary. In octal, each digit corresponds to exactly three binary digits, and in hexadecimal each digit is exactly four binary digits. This allows us to write binary numbers in much less space, and once you have memorized the binary digits that correspond to each octal or hexadecimal digit, the conversion is quite easy to do by sight. The conversion between binary and decimal is quite harder to do mentally.

As for how the calculations are performed, this is the topic of entire books. The simple answer is that they are performed by complex arrangements of simple binary logic gates. The complex answer is probably in the later chapters of those books you have been reading.

Comment: There's binary (base 2), octal (base 8), hexadecimal (base 16)... poor (base 4), it never gets a mention. What is it even called?

Comment: @NickHalden Seems like no one can decide if numeric prefixes should be greek or latin, but if wikipedia is to be believed, it's called [quaternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system).

Comment: @NickHalden i take that back...seems like they are all latin, except "hexadecimal" would have been "sexdecimal" and the prudes working in the Ministry of Computer Jargon thought that was not good.